# Percentage addition and multiplication

Tags: percentages

This is probably a stupid question, but thanks for the answer in advance.

I'm trying to build a simple expression calculator and I'm stuck on a problem
every calculator seems to treat differently:

100+10%*100

The question is what should be evaluated first, percentage addition or multiplication? Should the expression result to 110 or 11000?

Comment: first multiplication, then addition.

Answer (score 1):

$$100+10\text{%}\times 100=100+\frac{10}{100}\times100=100+10=110$$